# Viewing man pages with scroll wheel support

Tags: man, less, escape-characters, scrolling, pager

I'd like to use the scroll wheel (xterm mouse escape codes) to scroll through man pages, like I can in emacs with `xterm-mouse-mode`. less doesn't seem to have support for that and short of recompiling it I can't find a way to add it.

Is there a different pager I could use that supports the scroll wheel (or a way I could get less to do it)? I'd rather not give up bold and underline if possible.

My emulator is iTerm2 on Mac OS X Yosemite, if that helps.

Comment: I am a little confused by your question, because usually terminals already have a scrolling support in place to look at past output, so how would your system interact with the terminal exactly? Would it   override the existing one for the duration of the pager runtime?

Comment: @didierc: I'm not sure about the specifics, but basically it would use whatever escape code it is to tell the terminal that the alternate screen buffer supports xterm mouse codes and to report them to the program. I think both emacs and vim support them. (Quick edit: it's called [`alternateScroll`](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#Mouse%20Tracking).)

Comment: This is definitely possible. `less` and `man` scroll for me with the scroll wheel (in terminator). Unfortunately, I can't remember what I changed, if anything. [This](https://superuser.com/questions/455212/how-to-make-mouse-wheel-scroll-the-less-pager-using-bash-and-gnome-terminal) might be useful, but I can't understand where to set options.

Comment: @Sparhawk: What's your setup? Distro? coreutils? My `less` version is 418. I compiled less 458 and that didn't help, so it might be something else.

Comment: A request is [open](http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less/bugs.html) on the less features page for mouse support, so I'm not sure where it is that it has already been implemented. Compiled the beta too, still doesn't work.

Comment: @0942v8653 Arch Linux, less v471. It's not aliased to anything. I'm not sure if config options are stored anywhere. I can't see anything strange in `~/.bashrc`, but I wonder if the terminal emulator is important. I also just tried ssh-ing into my Debian Raspberry Pi, and it works there too with less v 458.

Comment: @Sparhawk: Hmm, 471 is the beta version I tried. As long as `TERM` is `xterm-256color`, then the emulator shouldn't matter. less configurations might be in environment variables—try `echo $LESS<tab>`.

Comment: Hm, that only gives `$ echo $LESSOPEN` -> `|/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s`. Also, scroll works in (KDE's) konsole, but not xterm (both have `$TERM=xterm-256color`).

Comment: @mikeserv: `lesspipe` is just a preprocessor, so it should not matter. It's possible the emulator is configured to send arrow keys for the scroll wheel in alternate screen mode—that seems to be the easiest option, if yours supports it.

Comment: @mikeserv FWIW I use bash. Also, as above, it also works over an ssh session (which is also bash), with no X forwarding.

Comment: @Sparhawk - do you have that `$LESS_TERMCAP_us` thing? Cool about the `ssh` thing - so you think it is `less` directly handling the mouse escapes or do you also use `terminator` on the other end of that `ssh`? If the latter then `ssh` shouldn't matter too much - I think recall reading somewhere that `ssh` doesn't do any terminal translation at all *(but I don't use it much either)*.

Comment: @mikeserv No, `echo $LESS` + <tab> will only autocomplete to `$LESSOPEN`. `$LESS_TERMCAP_us` is empty. I'm not even sure how I could have `terminator` on the other side, but anyway, it's not installed there.

Comment: @mikeserv Also, I just tried putting `set mouse=a` in my server's `~/.vimrc`, and now I can mouse scroll over `ssh` in `vim` too…

Comment: @mikeserv Ummm… I'm not sure. I'm not totally sure how `ssh` works. Is it not going straight into the console?

Comment: @mikeserv I thought I understood you now, but your last sentence confused me! :) However, I think we are on the same page now. I use `terminator` to `ssh` into the server, where my shell is `bash`. Oooooh… and if I use `xterm` as the emulator, I can't scroll in `man`, but I *can* in `vim`?! This is the same locally or via `ssh`.

Comment: @Sparhawk - yeah, its a concatenation of three edits - the last sentence was a reply to how `ssh` *(as I think I've read somewhere)* does no emulation in and of itself - its just a proxy between whatever `sshd` serves and your end-client receives. Weirdly, before I stumbled upon this question today, I spent an hour or so in `less`'s `man` page myself - which is why I'm chatty here. I think I'm going to stop calling my shell from the terminal's exec line and start calling `less` - which will then call my shell until I ctrl-z for whatever reason to grep the backbuffer in `less` at my leisure.

Comment: @mikeserv Ah nice. That sounds very interesting!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include your operating system. Since you mention iTerm2, I assume you're on a mac but you need to state that. I've been scrolling with the wheel in `less` for many years (at least 10) and in at least 4 different Linux distributions.

Answer (score 4):

I set my terminal emulator to send arrow keys for the scroll wheel when in alternate screen mode.

In iTerm2, that's under Preferences > Advanced and search for "scroll".

It doesn't interfere with xterm escape codes when something supports it, but when it does not (like in less), it sends arrow keys instead. Still not a complete solution, but better than nothing. (I think that's what Sparhawk's terminator was doing in the comment section above)

Comment: I don't know how it works, but my scroll wheel is definitely *not* just sending arrow keys. For example, in `vim`, scroll wheel scrolls the page, and arrows move cursor position.

Comment: That's because vim supports the scroll wheel. For me emacs is the same way—even when I turned that on, it worked the way it always has.

Comment: Ah okay. I just re-read your answer. That makes sense.

Comment: Where did you find Advanced in the Preferences of iTerm2?!

Answer (score 4):

[w3m](http://w3m.sourceforge.net/) can be a decent pager (though I do prefer less). It supports the mouse (you may need to enable this in the configuration), including scrolling.

[Vim](http://www.vim.org/about.php) is a text editor but can be used as a pager: set `PAGER='vim -R'`. You can [enable mouse support](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_the_mouse_for_Vim_in_an_xterm) with [`set mouse=a`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27mouse%27) in your `~/.vimrc`. The wheel works [at least in xterm](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/scroll.html#xterm-mouse-wheel), I can't vouch for OSX's terminal emulator.

Answer (score 1):

It seems this is possible using `WoMan` in `Emacs`.

According to http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WoMan “woman” stands for “w/o man”, ie “without man” and allows you to view man pages without having the “man” program installed.

In `Emacs` enter:

```
M-x woman
```

Where `M-x` is the `Alt` key followed by the letter `x`.

You will then be prompted to specify the `man page` you wish to view.

Comment: +1, this is helpful, but I'm really looking for an alternative pager. If there's nothing else I can use that, but I'd really rather stick to stock `man`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `cat`

```
man --pager=cat <page>
```

or you can pipe the man page into `cat`

```
man <page> | cat
```

Comment: My version of `man` (on a Mac) doesn't work with `--pager`, but more importantly cat starts at the end of the document and there's no easy way to get up to the top.

Comment: I want something that supports xterm mouse escape codes, and as I said, starts at the top.

Answer (score 0):

`PAGER='vim -R'` may result in some errors.
You can try this addon [vim-superman](https://github.com/jez/vim-superman).
if you met this error when executing `vman man`, you can try making your **font smaller** to solve it.

```bsh
    troff: <standard input>:587: warning [p 7, 8.0i]: cannot adjust line
```

You may find [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25507213/where-is-the-man-complete-function) helpful to solve the tab completion problem

```bsh
     bash: completion: function `_man' not found
```